# Should I use 'async' in QueueBackgroundWorkItem?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

Which code should I use?

```
HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem(task => DoTask())
```

or

```
HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem(async task => await DoTask()) 

private async Task DoTask(){
  await SomeThing();
}
```

Any different between them?

Comment: Don't do that.  Just use `async/await`

Comment: Thank you. So HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem(async task => await DoTask()) is correct? I want to know If I don't use async/await in QueueBackgroundWorkItem, how it goes, please.

Comment: No, I would do away with `QueueBackgroundWorkItem` entirely.  `Task` is the new way to do things along with `async/await` :)

Comment: When using QueueBackgroundWorkItem you schedule background task. Its safer then for instance not awaited Task - because ASP.NET "will try to delay AppDomain shutdown until these work items have finished executing". At the same time when you await task in request (like logging) you impair requests performance. So I would still use QueueBackgroundWorkItem and with await/async because I assume the background pool will be able to serve more tasks.